# Laravel relathionship with query builder get error

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have 3 tables this table is related to, I will call this table with

1. belanja (parent)
2. anak_belanja (child)
3. supplier (has relation with parent)

I can create this relation from parent and child but on table supplier I get an error. Usually I use "with" and I get no error, but now I use query builder and I have a problem

My Belanja Model

```
public function supplier()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Suplier::class ,'supplier_id');
}
```

My Anak_Belanja model

```
public function belanja()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Belanja::class ,'belanja_id');
}
```

and this is my controller

```
public function render()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $sub = SubRincianUraianKegiatan::where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->where('id' , $this->newid)
    ->pluck('uraian', 'id'); 
    $sup = Supplier::all()->pluck('nama' ,'id');
   
    $data = DB::table('belanja AS t')
    ->select([
    't.id',
    't.uraian',
    't.tgl_belanja',
    't.supplier_id',
    DB::raw('coalesce(sum(p.harga * p.qty),0) AS total_order')
    ])
    ->leftjoin('suplier AS s','t.suplier_id','=','s.id') // on here i think this error
    ->leftjoin('anak_belanja AS p','p.belanja_id','=','t.id')    
    ->where('sub_id', $this->newid)
    ->where('uraian', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
    ->groupBy('t.id')
    ->groupBy('t.uraian')
    ->groupBy('t.tgl_belanja')
    ->groupBy('t.suplier_id')
    ->paginate(10);

    return view('livewire.detail-belanja-lw',
    ['data' => $data ,
    'sup' => $sup,
    'sub' => $sub,
    ]);
}
```

In my blade I try to add supplier like that

```
 {{$i->supplier->nama}}
```

but I get an error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$supplier

Can someone explain my mistake?

Comment: you can't use relationship in query builder object. relationship works only with eloquent. so either use eloquent or select the supplier name and use it directly from the query builder.

Comment: i dont know how to do this sir , i need some example

Comment: you want to use eloquent or want to modify your current code??

Comment: i think modify is best because i dont need change my previous query ,please help me sir

Comment: then select supplier name too in your select. like `->select(['s.nama', ... ... ])` and use it as `{{ $i->nama }}`

Comment: where i can put this select ?

Comment: under this DB::raw ?

Comment: you have already a select statement. put just `'s.nama'` in there.

Comment: i not solved this sir , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = DB::table('belanja AS t')
->select([
't.id',
't.uraian',
't.tgl_belanja',
't.suplier_id',
DB::raw('coalesce(sum(p.harga * p.qty),0) AS total_order'),
DB::raw('s.nama as nama')
])
->leftjoin('suplier AS s','t.suplier_id','=','s.id') // on here i think this error
->leftjoin('anak_belanja AS p','p.belanja_id','=','t.id')    
->where('sub_id', $this->newid)
->where('uraian', 'like', '%'.$this->search.'%')
->groupBy('t.id')
->groupBy('t.uraian')
->groupBy('t.tgl_belanja')
->groupBy('t.suplier_id')
->paginate(10);
```

try this.

Comment: nooooo , its no , its not related with this query , i need solved in the variable $data

Comment: are you sure? because  {{$i->suplier->nama}}  suplier->nama come from this collection     $sup = Suplier::all()->pluck('nama' ,'id');

Comment: noo . i use this $sup for my form input . i use livewire so i can add this on my render . its not like this . my prblem on $data , its valid

Comment: I made changes to the code, in the select you have to add nama, and in the view for example if you have a foreach($data as $i) {{$i->nama}}

Comment: you just add DB::raw('s.nama as nama') ? but its still error

Comment: 1055 'project.s.nama' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `t`.`id`, `t`.`uraian`, `t`.`tgl_belanja`, `t`.`suplier_id`, coalesce(sum(p.harga * p.qty),0) AS total_order, s.nama as nama from `belanja` as `t` left join `suplier` as `s` on `t`.`suplier_id` = `s`.`id` left join `anak_belanja` as `p` on `p`.`belanja_id` = `t`.`id` where `sub_id` = 1 and `uraian` like %% group by `t`.`id`, `t`.`uraian`, `t`.`tgl_belanja`, `t`.`suplier_id`) as `aggregate_table`

Comment: Undefined property: stdClass::$suplier